# my QuickSort program is giving wrong output sometimes, mostly it is giving correct. can anyone solve the problem in my code?

Tags: java

here is my quicksort code. it is giving wrong output in some cases im not able to find the solution please help me.

```
    import java.util.Random;
    public class Sample
    {
        private static void swap(int[] a,int i, int j) {
            int temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
        }
        public static void quickSort(int[] a,int low, int high){
            if(low>=high) 
                return;
            int i=low; 
            int j=high-1;
            int piv=a[high];
//Partioning 
            while(i<j){
                while(i<=j && a[i]<=piv){
                    i++;
                }
                while(i<=j && a[j]>=piv){
                    j--;
                }
                if(i<j){
                    int t=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    a[j]=t;
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }
            if(a[i]>a[high])
                swap(a,i,high);
            else 
                i=high;
            quickSort(a,low,i-1);
            quickSort(a,i+1,high);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Random rand=new Random();
            int [] a= new int[10];
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
                a[i]=rand.nextInt(110);
            }
            // int[] a={15,23,93,2,35,8,50};
            System.out.println("before sort ");
            for(int e : a)
                System.out.print(e+" ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("after sort");
            quickSort(a,0,a.length-1);
            for(int e : a)
                System.out.print(e+" ");
        }
    }
    /* This is the output: it has a problem at 17.
    before sort
    22 55 16 98 78 17 1 36 24 95 
    after sort
    1 16 22 24 17 36 55 78 95 98 
    */
```

Comment: Try changing `while (i < j)` to `while (i <= j)`

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS thank you so much. may I know how did u solve the problem. I spent a lot of time but im not able to find it out. Thanks again.

Comment: If was honestly more of a guess, but since both your following while loops have the condition `while(i<=j` i figured the first while loop not using the same condition was likely a typo/bug. After all, if your outer loop makes sure `i` is always smaller than `j` then your inner loops allowing for both to be equal makes little sense.